# Why is Adam's name completely capitalized in the Good Omens character list?

Tags: neil-gaiman, terry-pratchett, good-omens

Before Good Omens has even started, officially, on page xiv in my copy, there's a list of characters. These include...

> SUPERNATURAL BEINGS
> God (God)
> Metatron (The Voice of God)
> [...]
> Satan (A Fallen Angel; the Adversary)
> [...]
> Crowley (An Angel who did not so much Fall as Saunter Vaguely Downwards)
>
> APOCALYPTIC HORSEPERSONS
> DEATH (Death)
> War (War)
> [...]
>
> THEM
> ADAM (An Antichrist)
> Pepper (A Girl)
> Wensleydale (A Boy)
> Brian (A Boy)
> [...]

As can be seen, the only two characters to have their names entirely capitalized are DEATH and ADAM. (Not even God gets entirely capitalized.)

Why is this? Why is Adam's name entirely capitalized here, even if he is the Antichrist, when even such characters as Satan and God don't get this same treatment?

Comment: I wonder if there's more significance than apparent in the standoff between Adam and Death near the end ... are those two characters paired somehow?

Comment: Confirmed from the latest ebook version.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - It's worth noting, then, that the Horsepersons are listed DEATH, War, Famine, Pollution; the Them ADAM, Pepper, Wensleydale, Brian. War fought Pepper, Famine Wensleydale, Pollution Brian.

Comment: Are they actually called Horsepersons in *Good Omens*? I thought the book went for the traditional name "Four Horsemen of the Apocalypse", despite some of them not being male (and none of them really *men* in the human sense anyway).

Comment: @Randal'Thor - https://i.imgur.com/YhpOblyr.jpg

Comment: @Randal'Thor:  They are definitely the horsepersons in the book.  Since when did Pratchett do traditional? (Igors notwithstanding)